# Suppose a satellite dish had the following surface patch parametrisation below...

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, surfaces, curves

Suppose a satellite dish had the following surface patch parametrisation:

$\textbf{r} : \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 ; \; (x.y) \mapsto (x, y, \frac{1}{4} (x^2 + y^2)) \in \mathbb{R}^3.$

https://w-dog.net/wallpaper/satellite-dish-sky-communication/id/202218/

**In which point do you have to mount the actual antenna in order to guarantee an ideal signal?** Explain and compute, proving first all that all incoming rays parallel to the central axis of symmetry are reflected into a common point.

I was told by my lecturer to first find the unit normal vector field to the surface patch:

$\textbf{N} (x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{4} x^2 + \frac{1}{4} y^2 + 1}}(-\frac{1}{2}x, - \frac{1}{4}y,1)$

I am also aware that rays parallel to the central axis of symmetry, will hit the dish at an angle $\alpha$ to $\textbf{N}$ and will bounce off at an angle $\alpha$ to $\textbf{N}$.

I am not really sure how to proceed from here.  How do I answer the question in bold?

Comment: You are familiar with the reflective properties of the parabola, no?

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician We have not really gone over it.  He said we need to deduce that ourselves.

Comment: Well, that's my hint. Simplify your problem by considering the parabola $y=x^2/4$ first.

Answer (score 0):

The property of the parabola is that all parallel rays reflect in one point that is its focus. If the equation is $y=\dfrac{1}{4}\,x$ focus is $1$ unit from the vertex

At point $(0,0,1)$

Hope This helps

$$...$$
[image]

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense.  However how do i relate that to the surface patch in my question?

Comment: @user432533 The focus is at $(0,0,1)$ it's the point where the antenna must be mounted